# Functions and continuity proof in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Prove:
If $f\colon A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ and $a\in A$, show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=b$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f^i(x)=b^i$ for $i=1,\dots,m$.

The end of the statement is where I'm slightly confused on the proof.

Comment: Write the proof.

Comment: What is meant by $f^i(x)$?

Comment: @drhab I can imagine that $f(x)=(f^1(x),\ldots,f^n(x))\in\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
$$\forall \varepsilon>0\quad\exists \delta>0, s.t\quad\|x-a\|<\delta\Rightarrow\|f(x)-f(a)\|<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow\|(f^1(x)-f^1(a),...,f^m(x)-f^m(a))\|<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow\quad \sqrt{(f^1(x)-f^1(a))^2+\cdots+(f^m(x)-f^m(a))^2}<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow \qquad\qquad\qquad\exists\varepsilon_i>0,i=1,2,...,m\quad,s.t\quad(f^i(x)-f^i(a))^2<\varepsilon_i^2$$